# SlideMenu won't close if link clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I have an off canvas menu that slides in when `isOpen` is toggled to true.  The problem is it won't slide back out on a `Link` click to go to another page.  The page loads but the mobile off canvas menu fills 100% of the screen.

`Header.js`

```
class HeaderContainer extends Component {
  state = { isMobile: false }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateHeader();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateHeader);
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateHeader);
  }

  updateHeader = () => {
    this.setState({ isMobile: window.innerWidth < 960 });
  }

  render() {
    const { isMobile } = this.state;
    return (
      <header>
        { isMobile  ? <MobileNav/> : <DesktopNav/> }
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

`MobileNav.js`

```
class MobileNav extends Component {
  state = { isOpen: false  }

  toggleMenu = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <MenuButton 
          toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}
          isOpen={isOpen}/>
        <SlideMenu isOpen={isOpen}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MobileNav;
```

`SlideMenu.js`

```
const SlideMenu = (props) => {


return (
    <Menu isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      <Nav>
        <StyledLink  exact to="/" activeClassName="selected">Home</StyledLink>
        <StyledLink to="/about" activeClassName="selected">About</StyledLink>
        <StyledLink to="/contact" activeClassName="selected">Contact</StyledLink>
      </Nav>
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about.
[image]

Comment: slideMenu has no function to toggle isOpen state. Onclick on styledlink .. this.props.toggleMenu should be called.

Comment: Called `onClick={props.toggleMenu}` and it gets rid of the slideMenu but doesn't change pages.

Comment: can you post code of .. styledlink component

Comment: I am using `styled-components` so it is just CSS in JS.

Comment: remove even.ptreventDefalt() from toglemenu

Comment: I wrote answer for others ..in case needed. You can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideMenu` has no function to toggle `isOpen` state. Onclick on `styledlink` .. `this.props.toggleMenu` should be called and `event.ptreventDefault()` should be removed from toglemenu

As discussed in the comment this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of state, use prevState `this.setState(prevState => {isOpen => !prevState.isOpen})`

Comment: How do I call `isOpen` down in the render function?